# How to dynamically create case_when() expressions based on variable names?

Tags: r, tidyverse, case

I have a dataframe with a set of revenue variables and a set of sales variables. I want to create a new set of variables that takes the value of the revenue variable and checks which sales variable it matches, and if it matches, it returns the corresponding year.

Here's a simplified example of what I have and what I'm trying to achieve:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

# Creating an example dataframe
df <- tibble(
  revenues_1 = c(1, 3, 4),
  revenues_2 = c(2, 4, 5),
  sales_2005 = c(1, 2, 3),
  sales_2006 = c(2, 3, 4),
  sales_2007 = c(3, 4, 5)
)

# What I want to do:
# df <- df |> 
#  rowwise() |>
#  mutate(
#    year_1 = case_when(
#      revenues_1 == sales_2005 ~ 2005,
#      revenues_1 == sales_2006 ~ 2006,
#      revenues_1 == sales_2007 ~ 2007,
#      .default = NA
#    ),
#    year_2 = case_when(
#      revenues_2 == sales_2005 ~ 2005,
#      revenues_2 == sales_2006 ~ 2006,
#      revenues_2 == sales_2007 ~ 2007,
#      .default = NA
#    )
#  )
```

However, this is not scalable if I have many years and many revenue variables.
How can I make this more efficient?

One idea is (not working):

```
# Create a list of expressions for each year
years_exprs <- map(2005:2007, ~parse_expr(paste0("var == 'sales_", .x, "' ~ ", .x)))

# Use this list in a case_when statement
df <- df |> 
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(across(starts_with("revenues_"), function(var) {
    case_when(
      !!!years_exprs,
      .default = NA
    )
  }, .names = "year_{.col}")) |> 
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, using your existing code you could use  `dplyr`'s `mutate`, `across` and `starts_with`, then place the function in a named list to create the new variables.

In order to reduce the effort to create individual `case_when`  logics for multiple years, you could first use `rlang::parse_exprs()` with `paste0`:

```
yrs <- 2005:2007
years_exprs <- rlang::parse_exprs(paste0(".x == sales_", yrs, " ~ ", yrs))
```

Then evaluate it using `!!!`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("revenues_"), 
                     list(year = ~case_when(!!!years_exprs))))
```

output:

```
  revenues_1 revenues_2 sales_2005 sales_2006 sales_2007 revenues_1_year revenues_2_year
       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
1          1          2          1          2          3            2005            2006
2          3          4          2          3          4            2006            2007
3          4          5          3          4          5            2006            2007
```

Note: if your variables don't necessarily all start with "revenues", you could create a vector of desired columns regardless if they share the same pattern (here, `mut_vars`), then use `all_of()`:

```
mut_vars <- c("revenues_1", "revenues_2")
df %>% mutate(across(all_of(mut_vars), 
                     list(year = ~case_when(!!!years_exprs))))
```

Comment: This is good but imagine you have 100 years...

Comment: yes but you would have to spell out sales_1900:sales_2000 in 100 rows right?

Comment: @Rico whoops yes, that was a copy paste error. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely needed to generate expressions you could do so like:

```r
library(glue)
library(tidyverse)

years <- 2005:2007
idx <- 1:2
years_exprs <- map_chr(idx, ~ {
  str_flatten_comma(c(glue("revenues_{.x} == sales_{years} ~ {years}"),
                      ".default = NA")) %>% 
    str_c("case_when(", ., ")")
                    }) |>
  set_names(paste0("year_", idx)) |>
  parse_exprs()


df |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(!!! years_exprs) |>
  ungroup()
```

You need to provide *named* expressions to `mutate` if you are going to use the split-slice operator `!!!`. The names will then become the variable names.

You can see how this expression will resolve after injection using `rlang::qq_show`:

```r
qq_show(
  df |>
    rowwise() |>
    mutate(!!! years_exprs) |>
    ungroup()
)

ungroup(mutate(rowwise(df), year_1 = case_when(revenues_1 == sales_2005 ~ 2005,
revenues_1 == sales_2006 ~ 2006, revenues_1 == sales_2007 ~ 2007, .default = NA),
year_2 = case_when(revenues_2 == sales_2005 ~ 2005, revenues_2 == sales_2006 ~
  2006, revenues_2 == sales_2007 ~ 2007, .default = NA)))
```

All that being said, if you could find a way to implement the solution provided by @jpsmith that would be a better practice. In my experience, people resort to using expressions in this way when they have data in a wide format. Often it is easier to pivot to a longer format or use available tools like `across`.

**Output**

```
  revenues_1 revenues_2 sales_2005 sales_2006 sales_2007 year_1 year_2
       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1          1          2          1          2          3   2005   2006
2          3          4          2          3          4   2006   2007
3          4          5          3          4          5   2006   2007
```

Comment: agree, maybe pivot to long format is easier but then it still is a somewhat complex lookup across rows. Do you have a suggestion? No worries if not.